# how to count a single value in a string and increment it 1 by one in php

Tags: php

i'm creating a simple and dynamic function for insert values in to mysql database table. so that problem is coming with the parameters binding. so i need to know how to count how many " ? " marks in that query string and how to increment it one by one. so if anybody have a good answer for this please let me know. This is the function i written to do this

```
function insertValues($table,$fields,$values){
    global $pdo;
    $field_include = '';
    $value_include = '';

    if(is_array($fields))
    {
        foreach ($fields as $key => $value) 
        {
            $field_include .= ($key == 0) ? $value : ','.$value;
        }
    }
    if(is_array($values))
    {
        foreach ($fields as $key => $value) 
        {
            $value_include .= ($key == 0) ? "?" : ','.'?';
        }
    }
    $sql = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$table.'('.$field_include.') VALUES ('.$value_include.')');

    $sql->execute(array($value_include));
```

thank you

Comment: whats the problem with this code?

Comment: i run this code without any errors.but there is an another error in my phpmyadmin table. it displays me the fields are empty. i don't know why is this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You earlier `$value_include` as a string with questionmarks. I think you need the use `$values` instad of `array($value_include)` in this line:

```
$sql->execute(array($value_include));
```

**Update:**

```
function insertValues($table,$fields,$values){
    global $pdo;
    $field_include = '';
    $value_include = '';

    if(is_array($fields))
    {
        foreach ($fields as $key => $value) 
        {
            $field_include .= ($key == 0) ? $value : ','.$value;
        }
    }
    if(is_array($values))
    {
        //Replaced $fields with $values 
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) 
        {
            $value_include .= ($key == 0) ? "?" : ','.'?';
        }
    }
    $sql = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$table.'('.$field_include.') VALUES ('.$value_include.')');

    $sql->execute($values);
```

Comment: then i use this as you told it says an error like this
 Array to string conversion

Comment: On which line? On `$sql->execute($values);` or another line?

Comment: $sql->execute($values); that line

Comment: Updated my question. Found another error in your second foreach loop. Also be sure your the `$values` variable is an array and is the same length as the `$fields` variable.

Comment: i fixed all of the errors coming from this function. but there is a other simple problem in my mysql database. so the rows are displaying with the empty values. i only can see the auto incremented field. but other fields are empty i don't know how to fix it